# Make bash commands to fall back to git commands if git command exists

Tags: linux, git, bash, command-line, terminal

Basically I want to type `show` and it checks if there is a `show` command or alias is defined and fire it and it is not defined fires `git show`.

For example `rm` should do `rm` but `checkout` should do `git checkout`.

Is it possible to program this in `bashrc`?

Comment: You could define aliases for all git commands

Comment: I prefer to have a program do this for me. But if there is no way for doing it then that would be a solution.

Comment: Sounds strange to me. What is the trigger to the fallback ? How to make a relation between whow and git ? oO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is surprisingly easy:

```
master tmp$ trap 'git $BASH_COMMAND' ERR
master tmp$ touch foo
master tmp$ rm foo
master tmp$ add foo
bash: add: command not found
fatal: pathspec 'tmp/foo' did not match any files
master tmp$ branch
bash: branch: command not found
  aix
  allocators
  ...
```

This runs the usual `touch` and `rm` commands, but because there is no `add` command it runs `git add foo` and because there is no `branch` command it runs `git branch`

The trap command is run on any error, so not only when a command isn't found.  You would probably want to do something smarter e.g. run a script which checks whether `$?` is 127 (the code bash sets when a command is not found) and then checks if running it with git instead would work (e.g. by checking for a command called `git-xxx` where `xxx` is the first word of `$BASH_COMMAND`).  I leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Yes, but is it relevant ? every-times the shell will have an error, it will pass the erroneous command to git.

Comment: As I said in the edit, you could handle that by checking what type of error you got and deciding whether to try running a git command instead

Comment: The command itself is interesting, but the process seems wrong. It's not a big deal to add an alias for each git commands.

Comment: The OP seems to feel differently, and asked if it's possible to do. I showed it's possible.

Answer (score 2):

There's no simple and proper way to achieve what you need. I think the best to do is to make an alias in `~/.bashrc` for every `git` commands.

But on many distros, if you check `man git`, there's some *Main porcelain commands* that looks like aliases.

You can list all of them using

```
PAGER= man git | grep -oP 'git-\w+(?=\()'
```

Answer (score 2):

When `bash` cannot find a command, it calls `command_not_found_handle` (if defined). You can define it to look something like this:

```
command_not_found_handle () {
    git "$@" || { echo "$1 not a 'git' command either"; exit 127; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias show='git show'
alias checkout='git checkout'
...
```

Be careful not to make an alias for a command that already does something else. This may break others programs.

Comment: I commented under my question that I want a programmatic way for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of getting a list of all your git commands:

```
git help -a | egrep '^  [a-zA-Z0-9]' | xargs -n1 | sed 's/--.*//' | sort -u
```

Or you could use what's in `contrib/completion/git-completion.sh`:  (This is probably better since you'll probably be looping anyway.  Note: You'll need to consider for duplicates, but they don't really matter for `alias`)

```
__git_list_all_commands ()
{
    local i IFS=" "$'\n'
    for i in $(git help -a|egrep '^  [a-zA-Z0-9]')
    do
        case $i in
        *--*)             : helper pattern;;
        *) echo $i;;
        esac
    done
}
```